# QGraphicsObject pointer added in QGraphicsScene is different when taken in QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I've a `SimpleStateShape` class that inherits `QGraphicsObject`:

```
#ifndef SIMPLESTATESHAPE_HPP_
#define SIMPLESTATESHAPE_HPP_

#include <QGraphicsObject>
#include <QSize>

class SimpleStateShape : public QGraphicsObject {

  Q_OBJECT

public:

  enum { Type = UserType + 1};

public:

  SimpleStateShape(const Style::CanvasSelfTransitionAnchor& selfTransitionStyle, const Style::CanvasTransitionAnchor& transitionStyle, const Style::CanvasSimpleState& style, QGraphicsItem* parent = nullptr);
  virtual ~SimpleStateShape();

public:

  QRectF boundingRect() const override;
  void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget) override;
  int type() const override;

private:

  QSize m_size;
};

#endif // !SIMPLESTATESHAPE_HPP_
```

This is the code that I use in order to add it to a `QGraphicsScene` contained in a subclass of `QGraphicsView`:

```
void Canvas::insertState(QMouseEvent* event) {
  if (m_insertingState) {
    auto sr = sceneRect();
    StateShapeVisitor visitor(m_style, nullptr);
    m_insertingState->accept(visitor);
    auto item = visitor.getStateShape(); // It returns a SimpleStateShape* tha I add.
    std::cout << "Adding state: pointer is " << item << std::endl;
    if (item != nullptr) {
      m_scene->addItem(item);
      item->setPos(mapToScene(event->pos()));
    }
    setSceneRect(sr);
  }
  emit clickedOnCanvas();
}
```

The method prints the pointer of the new shape:

```
Adding state: pointer is 000002576D94C9D0
```

Now I want to retrieve this shape with the mouse in a specific event. This is the code that I use in order to retrieve the shape under the mouse, check if it's a `SimpleStateShape` and return its pointer:

```
SimpleStateShape* Canvas::getStateUnderMouse(QMouseEvent* event) const {
  QGraphicsItem* item = itemAt(event->pos());
  if (item != nullptr) {
    SimpleStateShape* s = qgraphicsitem_cast<SimpleStateShape*>(item);
    if (s != nullptr) {
      std::cout << "returning shape: " << s << std::endl;
      return s;
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

When I run this method I write on console:

```
returning shape: 0000025774778800
```

The method finds an item, the item is a `SimpleStateShape` but the pointer is different. If I try to use some method of this class instance, my process crashes.

I'd like to know why the pointer is different, and how can I link the retrieve pointer to the object that I've created.

Comment: What is `StateShapeVisitor` and how `StateShapeVisitor::getStateShape()` function looks like?

Comment: Implementation details. According to business logic I retrieve a type of shape. In my example it returns a `SimpleStateShape` valid pointer. I forgot to refactor that part for removing it in the example sorry.

Comment: Difficult to say without a [mcve] but I'd hazard a guess that some other class might also be using `UserType + 1` as its type id.  That being the case `qgraphicsitem_cast` could be forcing the conversion hence the different addresses and subsequent crash.  Try a random'ish type id such as `UserType + 752` to see if that changes anything.  Ideally there should be some scheme by which classes can register their type ids to ensure they're all unique.

Comment: Further to my previous comment you might also want to try `dynamic_cast` rather than `qgraphicsitem_cast` as a 'safer' alternative.

Comment: I'm trying to create a reproducible example but it's not simple because it's not simple. I'll checked and every user type is different. I've tried also to put some unique random values for every user type that I use.

Comment: @Jepessen, I understand that the function returns a `SimpleStateShape` pointer, but, still, my question remains open.

Comment: Basically it's a node editor for state machines. I can have simple state, nested stated, parallel states, custom states and so on. These states inheriths a `StateShape` base class that inherits `QGraphicsObject`. They implement the visitor pattern so it's possible to the canvas to draw and use them without knowing their details.